# How to get the last character of a jobject in jni?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a jobject (ts) and I want to get the last character of it and then want to compare if it is equal to 0 or s (It is a mixture of numbers and characters). What can be the easiest way to do it?

```
jmethodID methodId_ts = env->GetMethodID(s_clazz,"toCharsString","()Ljava/lang/String;");
jobject ts = env->CallObjectMethod(signature,methodId_ts);
```

Comment: Use `GetStringUTFChars` or `GetStringUTFRegion`. Refer to [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for more details about those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ts.charAt(ts.length()-1)`:

```
jclass cls_String = env->GetObjectClass();
jmethodID mid_String_length = env->GetMethodID(cls_String, "length", "()I");
jmethodID mid_String_charAt = env->GetMethodID(cls_String, "charAt", "()C");

jint len = env->CallIntMethod(ts, mid_String_length);
jchar c  = env->CallCharMethod(ts, mid_String_charAt, len-1);
```